# Spark - Why am I getting "found : Int() required Integer" in an match case in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following udf function:

```
def DayBlock(t: Integer): Integer = {
  val Block = t match{
    case 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 24 => 4
    case 23 | 22 | 21 => 3
    case 19 | 17 | 20 | 18 => 2
    case 15 | 16 | 13 | 14 | 12 => 1
  }
  Block
}
val DayBlockUDF = udf[Integer, Integer](DayBlock)
```

But inside the case I am getting for each hardcode number the following error:

```
> error: type mismatch;  found   : Int(2)  required: Integer
>     case 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 24 => 4
```

I was looking for the solutions to similar problem on SO, and these are the three solutions I tried without success:

```
import spark.implicits._ 

@deprecated type Integer = java.lang.Integer

implicit def javaToScalaInt(d: java.lang.Integer) = d.intValue
```

What am I missing?

**Edit** based on the comments.

If I change the Integer by Int. Like this:

```
def DayBlock(t: Int): Int = {
  val Block = t match{
    case 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 24 => 4
    case 23 | 22 | 21 => 3
    case 19 | 17 | 20 | 18 => 2
    case 15 | 16 | 13 | 14 | 12 => 1
  }
  Block
}
val DayBlockUDF = udf[Int, Int](DayBlock)

val DayBlockDF = df.withColumn("newTime",DayBlockUDF($"oldTime"))
```

Then I have another error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (int) => int)

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.project_doConsume$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:350)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: 11 (of class java.lang.Integer)
```

Comment: Do you get any error if you use `Int` wherever you have used `Integer`? `Int` is `scala.Int`.

Comment: The problem is in the Dataframe the column is an Integer. I could try to make a cast of something, but I have the feeling I am missing an import with for implicit conversions, or similiar

Comment: Can you try with just `Int` in place of everywhere you have used `Integer`

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre  philantrovert  made a very good point - external Scala type for `IntegerType` is `Int`.

Comment: So what should I do? make a cast to Int in the column before calling the udf?

Comment: Replacing `Integer` with `Int` should be enough. Although it is workaround - `def DayBlock(t: Int): Int = { ... }`

Comment: As philantrovert pointed out, keeping it as `Int` should work, as Scala already takes care of the conversion: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html

Comment: I updated my question, with the error I get when changing the Integer to Int

Comment: You need a `case _` too and that should return an `Int` as well.

Comment: @philantrovert Ohh that last thing was it. There was also cases I wasn't taking into account x. Thanks add this in answer so I can accept it.